# Wordpress REST API returning empty responses

Tags: php, json, wordpress-rest-api

I am trying to interface with a Wordpress REST API. When I hit the endpoint in the browser, `http://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts`, the data is all there.

However when I actually try to query the Wordpress REST API using PHP, the response I receive is empty.

Here's the PHP:

```
$request = wp_remote_get( 'http://myurl.com/wp-json/wp/v2/users' );

$body = wp_remote_retrieve_body( $request );

$data = json_decode( $body, true );
```

`$data` is empty. The code works just fine with other json data, such as the data found here: `https://pippinsplugins.com/edd-api/products` as long as you remove the `true` parameter to indicate that it is not an assoc array.

Am I missing something obvious as to why I'm not getting any data back from this code snippet?

Comment: Did you check if `$body` is empty as well?

Comment: What happens if you test the rest endpoint with something like curl or Postman?

Comment: @Zeke yeah, $body is empty as well.

Comment: @tahsmith Hitting the endpoint works fine with Postman. Does require me to use basic auth though.